# Synchronizing audio and text to generate timestamp

Tags: audio, synchronization

We are working on synchronizing audio and text to generate timestamps for the content of the text file.

In our current problem statement, we are working on One of the World's oldest languages, Sanskrit. In this work, we are trying to get timestamps of the lyrical text file by matching it with the audio file.

Since Sanskrit is the oldest and has different pronunciations compared to other languages, As some words and symbols need to be pronounced for a longer duration and shortened the duration and in some scenarios no gaps between the words. Now matching text with audio is becoming a challenge for us.

We are expecting to synch Sanskrit audio file with lyrical text file.

We are open for collaboration to work on this problem statement?